# How can I upgrade while having unmet dependencies?

Tags: upgrade, apt, dependencies

I just install a package that has these unmet dependencies:
Depends: sun-java5-jre but it is not installable or
                sun-java6-jre but it is not installable or
                openjdk-6-jre but it is not installed

The above packages are not installable because I have install the newer version, the  openjdk-7-jre and the program is working fine. Looks like is has not updated its dependency list.

How I will be able to overcome this and avoid having the apt-get complaining?
It does not let me do the apt-get upgrade.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try passing the -m flag to apt-get to make it attempt to "ignore missing packages", this could possibly work.

See the man file of apt-get:

```
-m, --ignore-missing, --fix-missing
           Ignore missing packages; If packages cannot be retrieved or fail
           the integrity check after retrieval (corrupted package files), hold
           back those packages and handle the result. Use of this option
           together with -f may produce an error in some situations. If a
           package is selected for installation (particularly if it is
           mentioned on the command line) and it could not be downloaded then
           it will be silently held back. Configuration Item:
           APT::Get::Fix-Missing.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally fixed it by editing the /var/lib/dpkg/status file and ading the "openjdk-7-jre" at my package's dependencies line